# How can I define a event in typescript that has a typed data structure?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to have an array of events that each have a title and some data attached to them.
I want to have complete typings for them but can't figure that out right now.

I need an interface that has an **e** attribute for the title and **d** for the data. It should look something like this:

```
[
  {e: "ROLE_CREATED", d: { roleId: 2 }}, 
  {e: "ROLE_DELETED", d: { roleId: 3 }},
  {e: "USER_CREATED", d: { userId: 1 }}, 
]
```

I should not be able to insert a *USER_CREATED* event with a *roleId* into this array.

Answer (score 0):

This should catche errors

```js
type _Event<T extends string> = {
    e: `${Uppercase<T>}_${'CREATED' | 'DELETED'}`,
    d: Record<`${T}Id`, number>
}

const arr: (_Event<'role'> | _Event<'user'>)[] = [
  {e: "ROLE_CREATED", d: { roleId: 2 }}, 
  {e: "ROLE_DELETED", d: { roleId: 3 }},
  {e: "USER_CREATED", d: { userId: 1 }}, 
];
```

I would like to add that it could be a mistake to not call you ids `id`. Every user will have to know about the event type and do some work to reference the appropriate key when, maybe, all they really need to know is that it's an event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The id is just a placeholder. Sometimes I want to give full objects as the data. Sry that I didn't make that clear earlier. Still new to this platform

Comment: You can add `& { [key: string]: unknown }` to the definition of `d` in order to allow any other entry, or be more specific, like `& { foo?: number }` if you want to allow an optional known entry, `Record` will be required if you need to compute the key.